# Angular 5 service data not updating

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-services

I am slowing migrating from AngularJS to Angular(2+) and just stumbled across something.

In AngularJS, I used a lot of factories and services for sharing data across directives, controllers and other services. It is easy to update the service in one place and have it update everywhere else automatically.

However, I am trying to use a service in a similar manner in Angular 5 and "nothing is happening" when I change the service variables.

I've seen some solutions that involve creating functions that "pull" the new data or suggestions to update the "Angular change service" to bind events to the variable.

However, my app has many variables used in many locations. It doesn't seem correct that I have to subscribe to every single variable separately, within every single component that uses them, and change the service to emit a change for every single one.

Am I just missing something?

Thanks!!!
Wayne

For Example:

**A component for a home page.**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeButtonDirective } from '../home-button.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**The directive for a button that is reused on the home page:**

```
import { Directive, Input, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { InfoService } from './info.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHomeButton]',
  providers: [InfoService]
})
export class HomeButtonDirective {
  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onclick($event) {
    this.info.showHome = false;
  }
  constructor(private info: InfoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**The app component. Will show the home page if showHome===true:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { InfoService } from './info.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [InfoService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Testing a service';
  showHome = true;

  constructor(private info: InfoService) {
    this.showHome = this.info.showHome; // this works...showHome becomes false per the service (see below)
  }

 }
```

**And finally, the service:**

```
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class InfoService {
    showHome = false;
 }
```

Comment: Where is your service? Post your code

Comment: I know we require code to be posted, but Wayne's observations are correct and the question can be answered without additional information/code.

Comment: Thanks JasonK.  The question is code-agnostic. I can post some generic sample code, if it helps, but I didn't see the need to clutter the question with a few components, a directive and a service

Comment: @JasonK - Then you must be clairvoyant. There are many possibilities as to why "nothing happens" when a variable is "updated". Maybe a local copy is made of the data at the controller level, maybe the service is declared in multiple modules which results in multiple instances of the service instead of a singleton, maybe the data is not updated but an observable is or visa-versa, maybe the update does not actually change the service copy.... the list goes on.

Comment: @Igor Agreed. I'll try to post an answer to what I think is the problem.

Comment: Without an [mcve] this question cannot be answered. Any answer has to make assumptions as to why "nothing happens" and with the limited information that could be anything.

Comment: Iv'e added code. It is a subset of what the InfoService is intended to accomplish, but one of the duties will be to control which page/view is visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It is easy to update the service in one place and have it update
>   everywhere else automatically.?

Register the service with an Angular module rather than a component.

> from [Angular
>   docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#ngmodule-or-component)
>
> Angular module providers `(@NgModule.providers)` are registered with the
>   application's root injector. Angular can inject the corresponding
>   services in any class it creates. Once created, a service instance
>   lives for the life of the app and Angular injects this one service
>   instance in every class that needs it.

**To summarize**

If we want an instance of a dependency to be shared globally and share `state` across the application we configure it on the `NgModule.`

If we want a separate instance of a dependency to be shared across each instance of a component and it’s children we configure it on the components `providers` property.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head!!!!  That is exactly what I was unclear about. Changing the code accordingly fixed it! I removed "providers:[InfoService]" from each of the classes and added it to my list of providers in app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

I had the same observations when migrating from AngularJS to Angular.

### The problem

I'll use some sample code to describe the problem. Let's say we're building a `CommentComponent` to show comments, and the data is coming from a service named `CommentService`. We would then write something along the lines of:

```
this.comments: Array<Comment> = this.commentsService.commments;
```

This works perfectly fine during initialization. However, when data changes in the service (for instance when a new comment is pushed to the array), we won't see the changes reflect to our component. This is because the code above is just a direct (one-time) assignment inside the constructor, meaning there is no two-way binding.

### Possible solutions

There are multiple solutions to tackle the abovementioned problem. I'll share the ones that I'm aware of, but feel free to expand the answer.

---

**Using Observables**

In this case I prefer using [BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md) as it will immediately return the initial value or the current value on subscription.

```
private comments$: BehaviorSubject<Comment> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

... and subscribe to the observable in your component or whatever place you need the changes to be reflected:

```
this.commentsService.subscribe(comments => this.comments = comments);
```

---

**Referencing from templates**

Another solution (or workaround) is to reference to the service property directly from the template, which allows for two-way binding:

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of commentsService.comments">
    {{ comment | json }}
</div>
```

---

**Change Detection Strategy**

Another solution might be to adjust the [Change Detection Strategy](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html).

Answer (score 0):

in my experience, the variable you said may be an object, and you change the value of its property but itself.

you should change the object itself instead of changing his property.

so, if you want to change a complex object of a service, you'd better code looks like this:

```
this.oldObject = anotherObject
```

duplicate the old object to a new one if necessary.

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: My service has many variables. In the snippet above, the variable that isn't changing is a boolean.